# Simple, versatile and re-usable entry dialog (sometimes referred to as input dialog) in PyGTK

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

I am searching for a simple dialog with a text entry widget asking the user for some input. The dialog should be easy to run (like the `gtk.MessageDialog` variants) and as flexible.

There are of course some examples but they are either not flexible enough or too complicated to construct for my taste.

I hate re-inventing the wheel... or a dialog.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on an [example](http://ardoris.wordpress.com/2008/07/05/pygtk-text-entry-dialog/) I found (thanks [Ardoris](http://ardoris.wordpress.com/)!), I came up with a dialog subclass... hope it helps someone out there!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gtk
class EntryDialog(gtk.MessageDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''
        Creates a new EntryDialog. Takes all the arguments of the usual
        MessageDialog constructor plus one optional named argument 
        "default_value" to specify the initial contents of the entry.
        '''
        if 'default_value' in kwargs:
            default_value = kwargs['default_value']
            del kwargs['default_value']
        else:
            default_value = ''
        super(EntryDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        entry = gtk.Entry()        
        entry.set_text(str(default_value))
        entry.connect("activate", 
                      lambda ent, dlg, resp: dlg.response(resp), 
                      self, gtk.RESPONSE_OK)
        self.vbox.pack_end(entry, True, True, 0)
        self.vbox.show_all()
        self.entry = entry
    def set_value(self, text):
        self.entry.set_text(text)
    def run(self):
        result = super(EntryDialog, self).run()
        if result == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
            text = self.entry.get_text()
        else:
            text = None
        return text
```

The `run()` method returns either the text entered in the entry box if the user presses `<Enter>` or clicks Ok. If `Cancel` is clicked or `<Esc>` pressed, the `run()` method returns `None`.

Except for that, the dialog should behave as any other `gtk.MessageDialog` instance.

Maybe that is not *very* general as it assumes you will always have Ok as an option, but that is what I need in 99% of my use cases anyway.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't one available in GTK+. You've got two options:

- Create a dialog, pack the Entry and any other content you need (probably the best way in my opinion)
- Retrieve the content_area of the MessageDialog and append an Entry to it.

Something along the lines of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk

messagedialog = gtk.MessageDialog(parent=None, flags=0, type=gtk.MESSAGE_QUESTION, buttons=gtk.BUTTONS_OK, message_format="Hello")

action_area = messagedialog.get_content_area()

entry = gtk.Entry()
action_area.pack_start(entry)

messagedialog.show_all()
messagedialog.run()
messagedialog.destroy()
```

Though it does probably need more refinement to get the Entry to display nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the function I wrote, based on the previous answers here. It's a function instead of a class, which means you can use it in one line.

```
def get_text(parent, message, default=''):
    """
    Display a dialog with a text entry.
    Returns the text, or None if canceled.
    """
    d = gtk.MessageDialog(parent,
                          gtk.DIALOG_MODAL | gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
                          gtk.MESSAGE_QUESTION,
                          gtk.BUTTONS_OK_CANCEL,
                          message)
    entry = gtk.Entry()
    entry.set_text(default)
    entry.show()
    d.vbox.pack_end(entry)
    entry.connect('activate', lambda _: d.response(gtk.RESPONSE_OK))
    d.set_default_response(gtk.RESPONSE_OK)

    r = d.run()
    text = entry.get_text().decode('utf8')
    d.destroy()
    if r == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
        return text
    else:
        return None
```