# Python/Gtk3 : How to add a Gtk.Entry to a Gtk.MessageDialog?

Tags: gtk3, python-3.2

Good morning,

I'm trying to add a `Gtk.Entry` to a `Gtk.MessageDialog`. With the following code it seems that I added the `Gtk.Entry` but it's not visible on the dialog window **(Python3/Gtk3)**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from gi.repository import Gtk

def get_user_pw(parent, message, default=''):
    dialogWindow = Gtk.MessageDialog(parent,
                          Gtk.DialogFlags.MODAL | Gtk.DialogFlags.DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
                          Gtk.MessageType.QUESTION,
                          Gtk.ButtonsType.OK_CANCEL,
                          message)

    dialogBox = dialogWindow.get_content_area()
    userEntry = Gtk.Entry()
    userEntry.set_visibility(False)
    userEntry.set_invisible_char("*")
    userEntry.set_size_request(250,0)
    userEntry.set_text("Test")
    dialogBox.pack_end(userEntry, False, False, 0)
    #dialogWindow.vbox.pack_start(userEntry, False, False, 0)

    response = dialogWindow.run()
    text = userEntry.get_text() 
    dialogWindow.destroy()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        return text
    else:
        return None

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):

        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="MyWindowTitle")

        userPassphrase = get_user_pw(self, "SSH key passphrase")
        print("User passphrase: " + userPassphrase)
```

This code prints :

```
User passphrase: Test
```

I'm looking for clues about making the entry visible and editable, any help is welcome.

References:
http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dialogs.html
http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkDialog.html
[Simple, versatile and re-usable entry dialog (sometimes referred to as input dialog) in PyGTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290740/simple-versatile-and-re-usable-entry-dialog-sometimes-referred-to-as-input-dia)

---

Comment: you can answer your own question and accept the answer, so that the question doesn't remain open.

Comment: I couldn't do that at the time. I didn't have enough reputation points I think. Now it's done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok it works now, I needed to `show_all()` before `run()`. It took me some times to figure out this simple thing. Debugged code is :

```
def get_user_pw(parent, message, title=''):
    # Returns user input as a string or None
    # If user does not input text it returns None, NOT AN EMPTY STRING.
    dialogWindow = Gtk.MessageDialog(parent,
                          Gtk.DialogFlags.MODAL | Gtk.DialogFlags.DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
                          Gtk.MessageType.QUESTION,
                          Gtk.ButtonsType.OK_CANCEL,
                          message)

    dialogWindow.set_title(title)

    dialogBox = dialogWindow.get_content_area()
    userEntry = Gtk.Entry()
    userEntry.set_visibility(False)
    userEntry.set_invisible_char("*")
    userEntry.set_size_request(250,0)
    dialogBox.pack_end(userEntry, False, False, 0)

    dialogWindow.show_all()
    response = dialogWindow.run()
    text = userEntry.get_text() 
    dialogWindow.destroy()
    if (response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK) and (text != ''):
        return text
    else:
        return None
```

I use it like this :

```
class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="MyWindowTitle")
        userPassword = get_user_pw(self, "Please enter your password", "Password")
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be going about it the hard way if this is just to run a sudo command - you could simply call

`os.system('pkexec (yourcommand)')`