# How do I ask the user something in a dialog box with Gtk?

Tags: dialog, gtk, message, vala

I've recently started working on Gtk+ 3.x with the Vala programming language. I used to use C# and visual studio for much the same task, but have since moved to Linux.

How do I go about asking a simple Ok / Cancel question in a dialog? In C# it was really easy with MessageBox.Show(). However, Gtk seems to be annoyingly complex, and each Google search I have made has landed me with technical gibberish about Dialogs and event handlers.

Is there just a simple function, so I could do something like:

```
bool result = MessageBox.AskQuestion("Do you want to save?");
```

Thanks,

Barry Smith

Comment: `Gtk.Dialog` might help: http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Dialog

Comment: Here is a related question in python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970445/python-gtk3-how-to-add-a-gtk-entry-to-a-gtk-messagedialog

Answer (score 5):

Actually, found it out via trial and error...

```
public bool show_question(string message, Gtk.Window window, MessageType mt)
{
    Gtk.MessageDialog m = new Gtk.MessageDialog(window, DialogFlags.MODAL, mt, ButtonsType.OK_CANCEL, message);
    Gtk.ResponseType result = (ResponseType)m.run ();
    m.close ();
    if (result == Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can save some lines by writing `return result == Gtk.ResponseType.OK;`

Answer (score 3):

A slightly improved version:

```
public bool show_question(string primary_markup,
                          string? secondary_markup = null,
                          Gtk.Window? parent = null,
                          Gtk.MessageType message_type = Gtk.MessageType.QUESTION)
{
    var m = new Gtk.MessageDialog.with_markup(parent,
                                              Gtk.DialogFlags.MODAL,
                                              message_type,
                                              Gtk.ButtonsType.OK_CANCEL,
                                              primary_markup);
    m.format_secondary_markup(secondary_markup);
    var result = (Gtk.ResponseType) m.run();
    m.destroy();
    return (result == Gtk.ResponseType.OK);
}
```

This new version takes advantage of Vala's default parameters, so in the simplest case you can just call `show_question("Is this OK?");`. Furthermore, you can also now use [Pango Markup](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/PangoMarkupFormat.html) to generate much nicer looking dialogs, for example:

```
show_question("<b><big>Overwrite File?</big></b>",
              "<small>The file <i>\"%s\"</i> will be overwritten if you proceed</small>".printf(my_filename),
              parent_window,
              Gtk.MessageType.WARNING);
```

It's worth noting however that in GTK, using plain "OK/CANCEL" responses like this is generally frowned upon. Instead the recommendation is to use button labels that contain verbs pertaining to the action in question; so in the above example, "Cancel" and "Overwrite" would be much better options (defaulting to Cancel, of course). This takes a little but more work for the programmer, but provides a better user experience.